# Not broadening the type for properties I don't care about constraining

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an interface:

```
interface I {
  // Question: I only really care about constraining the input parameters
  fn: (s: string) => any
  val: any
}
```

My goal with this interface is just to assert that

- `val` is there, I don't care about constraining its type
- Make sure that `fn` is a function taking a `string`, but I don't care about constraining the return type

An example of using this would be:

```
const noice = {
  fn: (s: string) => s.length,
  val: new Date()
}

const test1: I = noice

test1.fn  // (property) I.fn: (s: string) => any
test1.val // (property) I.val: any

noice.fn  // (property) fn: (s: string) => number
noice.val // (property) val: Date
```

Is there a way to get rid of `any` so that I'll have the same specific type for `test1` as `noice` has?

Maybe it's `satisfies` nowadays? But what about before version 4.9 for those who haven't upgraded yet and for reading "legacy" code?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:typescript-generics], so maybe something like `const test1 = noice satisfies I<number, Date>;`? If you can't use `satisfies` yet, then: this is one of the reasons to upgrade.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes I thought it'll probably result in generics. But it might have been a bit premature. Hm, I guess there wer e no way before satisfies then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If you'd like to type up an answer using satisfies which also says that there really was no way earlier I'll for sure accept it. If you can't find the time I'll wait a week or two and then delete the question, to not "pollute" the search space of the intertubes. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on typescript >= 4.9 and you can use `satisfies` operator, you can do:

```
const x = noice satisfies I
```

Otherwise, you can do some workaround like this:

```
function enforce<Constraint>() : <T extends Constraint>(t: T) => T {
    return <T>(t: T) => t
}
```

Here, currying is used, so you don't need to specify the other type argument. Firstly, you call the first function with some constraint you want to hold, then call the second function, that will return the same argument. This obviously have some small runtime overhead.

```
const result = enforce<I>()(noice)
```